# Multiple after in "After X minutes after doing something"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say

1) X should do do A
2) After N minutes
3) After doing B

So if X needs to do A, X needs do B first. When N minutes have passed after doing B, then he can do A.

Can I use multiple 'after's in one sentence? Like, "X should do A after N minutes after doing B?"

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but do you mean, "X should do something first, but it has to wait N minutes before doing something else?" or a sentence like that?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: There is no need to use _after_ twice. 'X should do A N minutes after doing B.'